# WDS Router doesn't forward DHCP packets

Tags: networking, router, dhcp

Recently I have followed [this link](https://www.tp-link.com/lk/support/faq/447/) to setup a wireless router into an access point in my home.

Our current network components are as follows:

- **Main router (192.168.1.1)**: a Sercomm router configured by the ISP, with DHCP enabled for address 192.168.1.30 onwards.
- **AP router (192.168.1.2)**: a TP-Link WD8970 router on the bridge mode, with WDS turned on (on the same SSID, mode and channel as the main router) and DHCP turned off. However, this AP is configured to broadcast a different SSID to indicate a different storey.
- **Devices (182.168.1.xx)**: desktop or mobile clients that could connect to both SSIDs.

([click here for the topology image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxfUl.png))

The problem is that:

- Most of the time, devices connected to AP router's SSID is given 169.254.x.x IP addresses and could not reach the internet
- Devices that is configured with a dynamic IP and connected to the main router's SSID could reach only devices connected to the main router's SSID
- Devices that is configured with a static IP and connected to AP router's SSID could reach both routers (the main router at 192.168.1.1 and the AP router at 192.168.1.2, respectively)
- DHCP packets are not forwarded from the main router (192.168.1.1) to the AP router (192.168.1.2), while other types of packets could flow through

How would you advice on configuring this home network differently, to make it more stable and usable?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues in past days. I fixed checking the flag "DHCP RELAY". As soon as I checked it all went fine. All devices connected to the wireless router have received the IP address form DHCP server.
https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/faq/1630/ (the real configuration page on Archer D7 is slightly different form what stated in the link).

This was my network: I have a small usb powered 4G modem/router connected to internet. I wanted to share the internet with several devices located far from the 4G modem/router, so I decided to extend the coverage by means a TP-LINK Archer D7 ADSL modem/router used as Wifi access point. I connected the 4G modem to AP through WDS. The pc's and printers connected to Archer D7 (AP) were fine, security camera, smartphones etc.. no IP from DHCP. After the setting DHCP RELAY everything went fine.

Answer (score -1):

> Most of the time, devices connected to AP router's SSID is given 169.254.x.x IP addresses and could not reach the internet

This issue has to do with the WDS connection and poor connection from the AP to the main router. As a wifi expert (ok, expired CWNA) it's never a good idea to use WiFi extenders or WDS in your case. It increases interference, adds an extra hope, and rarely helps. While it's easy to think of these as a signal booster the wifi network protocol isn't setup for these types of connections. Only some commercial APs with parabolic antennas can truly benefit from wifi extenders.

Test with a cable connected from the main router to the AP and use the interfaces instead of wifi. It's possible you have DHCP issues with your wifi issue so first test with static IPs.

If this works then you should leave the cable in place. Understandably this isn't always possible so replacing your main router with a quality wifi router would be my 2nd choice. Sorry I don't know any good consumer grade APs but they are out there.